# How to evaluate $3^{123}\!\bmod 3\,$ and $5^{123}\! \bmod 2$ and similar?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I hope someone can explain me how to solve modulo -equations ,e.g.

$5^{123} \mod 2$

It was a little bit overwhelming for me to get a feeling for solving such equations.I don't how and when i have to use  one of these great theorems like, Fermat's little ,Euler totient function,Chinese remainder theorem a.s.o.So I decide to  ask you guys for helping  me with my stacks.

Comment: In this case , the result is obvious : $0$

Comment: Tip for the general case : Use the chinese remainder theorem and the Euler theorem (sometimes Fermat's little theorem is already sufficient)

Comment: Ok,you are right.It is a bit trivial example.

Comment: Maybe 5^123 mod 2 should be better.

Comment: I heard in this context about this three( not so trivial ) theorems but  hoping I get the algorithm  from someone  who explaining it to me by an example 

Comment: @Gui A few points. This question will be "closed" soon, and (somewhat later) deleted. Why? Partly because the particular example you picked initially was so trivial. But mainly because you tried to modify it in the comments instead of in the question. Comments are NOT for modifying the question. They are for others to get you to clarify the question. If the question needs changing, you should edit it, not make comments on it!

Comment: $3$ is easy if $k|3$ then $3^n\equiv 0$.  If $k\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ then $k^n\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and if $k\equiv -1 \pmod 3$ then $k^n\equiv (-1)^n\pmod 3$.  ANd for $5^{123}\pmod  2$ then $5\equiv 1 \pmod 5$.  But in general, Euler's Th. and C.R.Theorem can do it.

Comment: This shouldn't be on hold but it is a duplicate (although I'm too lazy to find it).  But 1) If $p$ is prime and $k$ is not a multiple of $p$ then Fermat's little Theorem says $k^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ and so if $n \equiv m \pmod{p-1}$ you have $k^n\equiv k^m \pmod p$. so example $7^{5342}\pmod {11}\equiv 7^{534*10 + 2}\equiv (7^{10})^{534}*7^2\equiv 1^{534}*7^2\equiv 1*7^2\equiv 7^2\equiv 49\equiv 5\pmod{11}$.

Comment: @Gui Since this one is closed, I posted in another similar one, vote if you like https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3364841/399263

Comment: 2) If $n$ isn't prime but $\gcd(a,n)=1$ then Eulers theorem says that $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod n$ where $\phi(n)=$ number of integers less than $n$ that are relatively prime to $n=\prod_{p_i^{a_i}|m} (p_i-1)p_i^{a_i-1}$. So for example $7^{5342}\pmod {40}$ we have $\phi(40=2^3*5)=2^2*4=16$ and $5342\equiv 14\pmod{16}$ so $7^{5342}\equiv 7^{14}\pmod 40$. And well, $7^2\equiv 49\equiv 9\pmod {40}$ and $9*9\equiv 81\equiv 1\pmod {40}$ and $7^{14}7^{2}\equiv 1\pmod {40}$ we have $7^{14}\equiv 9\pmod {40}$.

Comment: But google 1) Euler's theorem, 2) Fermat's Little Theorem and 3) Chinese remainder Th.  and see how this in combination can solve all.

Comment: firstly ,I must thank you all for your amazing help.!!But know I must go offline to work  on your specific  comments .

Comment: If you want to solve, say $6^{5342}\pmod {33}$ then solve $6^{5342}\pmod{3}$ and $6^{5342}\pmod {11}$.  $6^{5342}\equiv 0 \pmod {3}$ and $11$ is prime so by FLT $6^{10}\equiv 1\pmod 11$ and $6^{5342}\equiv 6^{2}\equiv 36\equiv 3\pmod {11}$.  So by Chinese Remainer The there is one solution to $3\pmod{11}$ and $0\pmod 3$ mod $33$ and that is $3\pmod {33}$ so $6^{5342}\equiv 3\pmod{33}$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is pretty obvious: it is $0$ ($3^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer obviously divides $3$ and thus has a remainder of $0$). If you were asking for$\pmod{10}$, then we would apply Euler's Totient's Function, $\phi(n)$ and then simplify from there. For your next question, since $5\equiv 1\pmod 2$, we have that $$5^{123}\equiv 1^{123}\equiv 1\pmod{2}.$$

Comment: I will try it for $5^{123}$ mod 10:

Comment: 5 is the answer then. As any odd multiple of 5 ends in a 5 in base 10.